# How to change which file manager the keyboard shortcut points to in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, filemanager, plasma-5

(Kubuntu 18.04, KDE Plasma 5.12.9)

I'd like to try *Krusader* in place of *Dolphin* and would like to continue using <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as the keyboard shortcut. After installing *Krusader*, I did the following:

1. I opened *System Settings* from the application menu.
2. I looked under the *Workspace* heading, clicked *Shortcuts -> Global Shortcuts -> KDE Daemon* and found the entry *File Manager: <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>*. I made no changes here.
3. Back in the main window of *System Settings*, under the *Personalization* heading I went into *Applications -> Default Applications -> File Manager*.
4. I selected the radio button *Other: click Add... in the dialog shown here* and clicked the *...* button next to it.
5. I was presented a dialog box entitled *Edit File Type inode/directory -- File Type Editor*. In the lower panel entitled *Application Preference Order* I clicked the *Add* button.
6. I was presented a dialog box entitled *Choose Application for inode/directory -- File Type Editor* with the a tree listing of application categories found in my application launcher. I selected *Utilities -> Krusader*, which added *Krusader* at the top of the list of applications in the *Application Preference Order* panel.
7. I clicked *OK*, there was a dialog box that gave an indication that something was being updated. When done, in the *File Manager -> Default Component* list I selected *Krusader* and clicked *Apply*.
8. As it was in the *KDE Daemon* category, not knowing how to restart a daemon without rebooting the computer, I went ahead and rebooted.

Unfortunately, <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is still bringing up *Dolphin*. I did discover, though, when right-clicking an empty spot on the desktop, the context menu has an entry, *Open with Krusader <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>* which does work. I don't know where this shortcut is defined. I can use that in a pinch, but would prefer <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Any suggestions?

[image: Global Shortcuts -> System Settings]
[image: KInfocentre]

Comment: Apologies for the backticks. `plasmashell -v` gives "5.12.9" and `dolphin -v` gives "17.12.3".

Comment: That's what I have too. But I don't see the Meta+E shortcut. AFAICT, it's not available in Kubuntu 18.04. See https://phabricator.kde.org/D19831

Comment: Very strange indeed. I assure you though, that "Meta+E" does launch Dolphin. Oddly, I've just brought "System Settings" back up, and the "File Manager" shortcut has migrated from "KDE Daemon" to "System Settings", and is still set for "Meta+E". On my system, "Meta" refers to the MS logo key.

Comment: Screenshot added to post

Comment: Screenshot added to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** this answer is **speculative** because I don't see the <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut to launch the file manager on my Kubuntu 18.04!

---

- Open *System Settings* > *Shortcuts* > *Custom Shortcuts*
- Click on *Edit* > *New* > *Global Shortcut* > *Command/URL*
- In the interface that appears,

  - for the *Comment* enter  a suitable description,
  - for the *Action*, enter *krusader*,
  - for the *Trigger*, in the box next to *Shortcut* click on *None* which will change to *Input*,
  - press <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.
  - You'll probably get a beep and a window will appear to warn you that <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> conflicts with the shortcut assigned to *File Manager*.
  - Click on *Reassign* to override the existing setting thereby setting <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to launch *Krusader*.
  - Click *Apply*.

From now on, <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will launch *Krusader*.

---

Re.

> … I did discover, though, when right-clicking an empty spot on the desktop, the context menu has an entry, *Open with Krusader
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>* which does work. I don't
>   know where this shortcut is defined. …

In Kubuntu 18.04 or 19.04, right-clicking on the desktop pops up a context menu with one option being *Configure Desktop*. Choosing that opens a new window. Select mouse actions on the left and then, next to the dropdown for Right button there's a settings icon. Clicking on that has the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd> setting (among others). For me, on both systems, it's already there and set to Open with Dolphin by default. In your case, it reflects your preference for *Krusader*.

The image below is from Kubuntu 19.04 with Plasma 5.16.5 and so the icons aren't the same as those in Kubuntu 18.04:

[image: Standard menu options]

Comment: Thanks! Any idea where the original "Alt+D,T" was set? I certainly didn't set it myself.

Comment: I have edited the answer to cover the *Alt+D,T* aspect.